# What are the negatives of soy templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, web

Very general question:  I am researching templating options, and I was wondering if anyone could enlighten me as to the cons of google closures using soy templates?  I see lots of examples of their uses, and their simplicity, but nothing about any pitfalls.

I am a big fan of what they offer, but I would like to hear what other people have to say...

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

For those of you who have no idea what I am talking about, here is a link to a hello world example: [link](http://code.google.com/closure/templates/docs/helloworld_js.html)

Comment: One con, perhaps: as someone who is reasonably aware of the HTML templating space, I have never heard of them. So I kind of doubt they're widely used. Maybe it's a Google ecosystem thing.

Comment: Really?  You should check them out, they are pretty nifty.  This can be used in either server side or client side rendering.  Google provides a jar to compile the templates to either JS or Java.  http://code.google.com/closure/templates/docs/helloworld_js.html

Comment: Are you referring to closure templates as found in .soy files?

Comment: Worst thing is you need to recompile every time you change in html.